# How to fix browser Uncaught Error: Script error for "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" ng-boostrap Bazel

Tags: angular, bazel, ng-bootstrap

I'm getting a runtime error in the browser:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1 Uncaught Error: Script error for "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap", needed by: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.ngfactory, project/src/app/app.component.ngfactory, project/src/app/app.module.ngfactory, project/src/app/app.module
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (bundle.min.js?v=1567992324291:169)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (bundle.min.js?v=1567992324291:1739)
    at e.invokeTask (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
    at t.runTask (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
    at _ (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.m (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
```

I have tried:

## Try 1 [angular-bazel-example fork](https://github.com/conalryan/angular-bazel-example/blob/ng-bootstrap/ngbREADME.md)

Fork [angular-bazel-example](https://github.com/angular/angular-bazel-example)

1. Add ng-bootstrap

```sh
yarn add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

2. Add ngb to angular-metadata.tsconfig.json

```
"node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/**/*"
```

3. Run postinstall

```sh
yarn run postinstall
```

4. Add alert to app.component

```html
<ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</ngb-alert>
```

5. Add NgbAlertModule to app.module

```js
import {NgbAlertModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
// ...
imports: [
  //...
  NgbAlertModule,
  //...
]
```

6. Add ng-bootstrap to src/BUILD.bazel

```
deps: [
  # ...
  "@npm//@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"
  # ...
]
```

7. ng serve

```sh
ng serve
```

Browser ERROR:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.min.js:19 Uncaught Error: Script error for "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap", needed by: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.ngfactory, angular_bazel_example/src/app/app.component.ngfactory, angular_bazel_example/src/app/app.module.ngfactory, angular_bazel_example/src/app/app.module
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (ts_scripts.js:174)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (ts_scripts.js:1744)
    at e.invokeTask (zone.min.js:19)
    at t.runTask (zone.min.js:19)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.min.js:19)
    at _ (zone.min.js:50)
    at HTMLScriptElement.m (zone.min.js:50)
:5432/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

8. ng build

```sh
$ ng build
Your global Angular CLI version (8.2.2) is greater than your local
version (8.1.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
DEBUG: Rule 'io_bazel_rules_k8s' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying ar
guments shallow_since = "1563971973 -0400"
DEBUG: Call stack for the definition of repository 'io_bazel_rules_k8s' which is a git_repository (rule defin
ition at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_cryan/ae53ea6e5cfa8e1630282da1d8a7c11d/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:181:18):
 - /Users/cryan/code/t/angular-bazel-example/WORKSPACE:123:1
INFO: Analyzed target //src:prodapp (163 packages loaded, 2122 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /Users/cryan/code/t/angular-bazel-example/src/BUILD.bazel:122:1: Bundling JavaScript src/bundle_chunks
_es2015 [rollup] failed (Exit 1) rollup failed: error executing command bazel-out/host/bin/external/build_baz
el_rules_nodejs/internal/rollup/rollup --config bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/src/_bundle.rollup.conf.js --o
utput.dir ... (remaining 3 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
[!] (commonjs plugin) Error: Could not resolve import 'angular_bazel_example/external/npm/node_modules/@ng-bo
otstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.ngfactory' from '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_cryan/ae53ea6e5cfa8e1630282da1d8a7c11d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/128/execroot/angular_bazel_example/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/src/bundle.es6/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js'
Error: Could not resolve import 'angular_bazel_example/external/npm/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.ngfactory' from '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_cryan/ae53ea6e5cfa8e1630282da1d8a7c11d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/128/execroot/angular_bazel_example/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/src/bundle.es6/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js'
    at Object.notResolved (/private/var/tmp/_bazel_cryan/ae53ea6e5cfa8e1630282da1d8a7c11d/execroot/angular_bazel_example/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/src/_bundle.rollup.conf.js:163:11)
    at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_cryan/ae53ea6e5cfa8e1630282da1d8a7c11d/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/128/execroot/angular_bazel_example/bazel-out/host/bin/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/rollup/rollup.runfiles/build_bazel_rules_nodejs_rollup_deps/node_modules/rollup-plugin-commonjs/src/utils.js:20:68

Target //src:prodapp failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 275.586s, Critical Path: 54.27s
INFO: 39 processes: 1 darwin-sandbox, 38 worker.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
/Users/cryan/code/t/angular-bazel-example/node_modules/@bazel/bazel-darwin_x64/bazel-0.28.1-darwin-x86_64 failed with code 1.
```

9. Diff
   https://github.com/angular/angular-bazel-example/compare/master...conalryan:ng-bootstrap?expand=1

## Try 2 [ng new ng-bootstrap-bazel](https://github.com/conalryan/ng-bootstrap-bazel/blob/feature/ng-bootstrap/README.md)

1. Init new project

```sh
ng new ng-bootstrap-bazel
# select routing and scss for styles
```

2. Add ng-bootstrap

```sh
yarn add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Add ng-alert to app.component.html

```html
<ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</ngb-alert>
```

Add NgbModule to app.module

```js
import {NgbAlertModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
// ...
imports: [
  //...
  NgbAlertModule,
  //...
]
```

Build and run

```sh
ng build
ng serve
```

3. Add Bazel

```sh
ng add @angular/bazel
```

Add ng-bootstrap to `angular-metadata.tsconfig.json`

```
"node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/**/*"
```

Add ng-bootstrap to BUILD.bazel

```
"@npm//@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap",
```

Postinstall task:
Runs ngc on "included" node_modules

```sh
yarn run postinstall
```

After ngc there will be a .ngfactory.js file in the node_module

```
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
ng-bootstrap.ngfactory.js
```

Build with Bazel via Angular CLI

```sh
ng build --leaveBazelFilesOnDisk
```

Add `"@npm//@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap",` to //src:bundle deps

```
"@npm//@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap",
```

```sh
bazel run //src:deverserver
```

Browser ERROR:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1 Uncaught Error: Script error for "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap", needed by: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.ngfactory, project/src/app/app.component.ngfactory, project/src/app/app.module.ngfactory, project/src/app/app.module
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (bundle.min.js?v=1567992324291:169)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (bundle.min.js?v=1567992324291:1739)
    at e.invokeTask (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
    at t.runTask (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
    at _ (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.m (zone.min.js?v=1567992324291:1)
```

I'm assuming I'm missing some configuration?

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Not sure what's going on behind the scenes, but I was able to resolve by having bazel manage my node_modules and doing a fresh build after deleting node_modules

Answer (score 0):

if you see the file from `node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.umd.js`,you would know that it define `ngb`,not the `ng-bootstrap`.So you should create a file to define `ng-bootstrap`, refer to `ngb`, like the `rxjs_shims.js`.

Comment: And what happen if module is anonymous? Like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge